# Android SwitchedService class design, for cases where you want to start/stop a service from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: java, android

I could use some feedback on the class I designed for the above purpose, the complete code is here:

https://github.com/tom-dignan/android-switched-service/blob/master/src/com/tomdignan/android/libs/switchedservice/SwitchedService.java

My main question is, does this make sense for its intended purpose?

But I will paste it all for convenience. Much of the class is explained in the doc-blocks.

```
package com.tomdignan.android.libs.switchedservice;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;

/**
 * SwitchedService is a Service that can truly be turned on and off.
 * 
 * Android's nomenclature for sending messages to a Service is "startService"
 * when the task performed is really to "start if not started, and send a message". 
 * A call to stopService does not guarantee any sort of callback by the Service itself 
 * to be called. "onDestroy" is to be called "by the system to notify a Service that 
 * it is no longer used and is being removed" and therefore cannot be used to tell the 
 * service to "stop doing something" which is what would seem should be the intended 
 * purpose. This is really bothersome when calling the Service from a BroadcastReceiver, 
 * which cannot bind to the Service. This leaves only one solution, calling startService 
 * with an Intent that identifies whether the service is being started or stopped.
 * 
 * @see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html
 */
abstract public class SwitchedService extends Service {

    //=========================================================================
    // Static Helpers for Special Start/Stop cases
    //=========================================================================

    /** 
     * Does the tedious work of starting the service. Vanilla case,
     * no extras.
     * 
     * @param context
     * @throws NoSuchServiceException thrown if ComponentName is null, i.e.
     * the service does not exist.
     */
    public static void startService(Context context, Class<?> service) 
            throws NoSuchServiceException {
        sendIgnitionMessage(context, service, START);
    }

    /**
     * Stops the service. This wrapper is the most important one, because
     * it has to call "startService" which is a counter-intuitive name
     * if one intends to actually stop the service with said method call.
     *
     * The reason for this is that "stopService()" does not have a callback.
     *
     * This enables us to have an "onStop()" callback.
     */
    public static void stopService(Context context, Class<?> service)             
            throws NoSuchServiceException {
        sendIgnitionMessage(context, service, STOP);
    }

    /**
     * Helper method that accomplishes the goal of both startService and
     * stopService.
     * 
     * @param context
     * @param service
     * @param ignition
     * @throws NoSuchServiceException
     */
    private static void sendIgnitionMessage(Context context, Class<?> service, int ignition) 
            throws NoSuchServiceException {
        // Create the intent needed to start the service.
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, service);

        // Tell the service that this intent is meant to start/stop it.
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_IGNITION, ignition);

        if (context.startService(intent) == null) {
            throw new NoSuchServiceException();
        }
    }

    //=========================================================================
    // The exception that should be thrown when a ComponentName is null
    //=========================================================================

    public static class NoSuchServiceException extends Exception {
        /** For serialization */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1823049847998820645L;
    }

    /** 
     * Identifier for the EXTRA that must be sent in the Intent that
     * starts the BetterService
     */
    public static final String EXTRA_IGNITION = "IGNITION";

    /** Identifier for when the service is being started */
    public static final int START = 1;

    /** Identifier for when the service is being stopped. */
    public static final int STOP = 2;

    /** 
     * Identifier for when the caller did not remember to use START
     * or STOP to throw exception.
     */
    public static final int WRONG = 3;

    /** Implement onStart logic here */
    public abstract void onStart();

    /** Override this to hook service stops */
    public abstract void onStop();

    /**
     * Calls either onStart or onStop depending on EXTRA_IGNITION. Always
     * starts
     */
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        int ignition = intent.getIntExtra(EXTRA_IGNITION, WRONG);

        switch (ignition) {
        case START:
            onStart();
            break;

        case STOP:
            onStop();
            stopSelf();
            break;

        case WRONG:
            throw new IllegalStateException("You must specify START or STOP for EXTRA_IGNITION");
        }


        // We only want to start and stop it ourselves.
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    //=========================================================================
    // Unused
    //=========================================================================

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // NOOP
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Some small notes:

1. Comments like this are unnecessary:

   ```
    * @param context
    * @param service
    * @param ignition
    * @throws NoSuchServiceException
   ```

   It says nothing more than the code already does, it's rather noise. (*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*: *Chapter 4: Comments, Noise Comments*)
2. ```
   throw new NoSuchServiceException();
   ```

   Consider filling the exception with some information which helps debugging (service, intent, etc., for example).
3. Consider declaring the `onStartCommand` method as `final` to prevent accidental overriding.
4. Have you considered using composition over inheritance? See: *Effective Java, 2nd Edition*, *Item 16: Favor composition over inheritance*